# Where to configure global consistency level in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

We have setup multidatacenter replication in Cassandra and identified that we need to configure consistency level as Each_Quorum (refer [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html)). But I am unable to figure out where exactly I need to configure this consistency level, please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consistency is configured at client level, what client are you using to connect to cassandra?

Comment: Our requirement is to use it in multi-datacenter replication in which client doesn't come into the picture. The document I have referred here states "You can configure consistency on a cluster, datacenter, or per individual read or write operation. Consistency among participating nodes can be set globally and also controlled on a per-operation basis". So our requirement is to setup globally.

Answer (score 1):

Consistency is defined at the client level.

When the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.x/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html) states:

> You can configure consistency on a cluster, datacenter, or per individual read or write operation.

it refers that the different levels have different granularity, `ALL` and `EACH_QUORUM` will return a value once that it has gotten consensus from all the datacenters (in other words, cluster-wide); `LOCAL_ONE` and `LOCAL_QUORUM` can limit to validate the nodes on a single datacenter, with a replication factor of 1 and a consistency level `ONE` will guarantee that only one node will be taken in consideration. You can have a different consistency levels between reads and writes

> Consistency among participating nodes can be set globally and also controlled on a per-operation basis.

This also refers to the driver side; for example, for Java with the Datastax driver, you can define the consistency level on the `Session` Interface with the attribute `consistencyLevel` of [MappingManager](https://datastax.github.io/java-driver/manual/object_mapper/), or specify the consistency on each one of the queries with the `execute()` method.